# Where can I get an editable PDF character sheet for Doctor Who: Adventures in Time and Space?

Tags: character-sheets, doctor-who-roleplaying-game

I am a new GM, and need to write up a number of character sheets for NPCs, for my campaign in Doctor Who- Adventures in Time and Space. I would much prefer to do this by typing into the PDF of the sheets, but the official ones I have from DriveThruRPG are read-only. I'd also like to be able to do this for my players' character sheets eventually, to keep things tidy.

Does anyone know of an editable version? I don't mind if it is the 10th or 11th Doctor edition, the difference is only cosmetic.

Comment: Just FYI, if you have a copy of Adobe Acrobat Pro you can make the PDFs you have editable yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a pretty good [fillable character sheet on the Doctor Who forum](http://dwaitas.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=prevs&action=display&thread=307).

The only downside is that you have to register in order to download the file, but it also seems to have some good content on the forums as well.

I downloaded it and [mirrored it here](http://www.4shared.com/office/5-7LOa5t/Dr_Who_Character_Sheet_Fillabl.html) for safe keeping (and to save the hassle).